# python condition before statement

Tags: python, conditional-statements

In Go one is able to use conditionals before statements lie this:

```
if num := 9; num < 0
```

I would like to do the same in python.
I'm creating a function that returns the status of the result and the actual result if it was successful, like this:

```
def myfunc:
  val = 0
  if val > 0:
    return [ True, val ]
  else:
    return [ False, val ]
```

So I want to use it like so:

```
if res, val = myfunc() TEST FOR res:
  do_something()
```

Comment: Does the return value need to be accessible afterwards? Then write it on two separate lines. Otherwise: `if myfunc()[0]:`…

Comment: Why a separate boolean? You can do something like `if (valid_condition): return val; else: return None` and then test for `None`.

Comment: yep, i want to be able to assign res,val=myfunc() and on the same line test for res, and use the val in the if block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible in python. Just put it in two lines e.g.

```
res, val = myfunc()
if res:
    do_something()
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Python 3.8, you can use an [assignment expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/):

We assign the output to a tuple `out`, and test if its first item is `True`:

```
def myfunc(val):
  if val > 0:
    return [ True, val ]
  else:
    return [ False, val ]

if (out := myfunc(5))[0]:
    print(out)
else:
    print('That was False')
# [True, 5]


if (out := myfunc(-2))[0]:
    print(out)
else:
    print('That was False')
# That was False
```

Sadly, we can't unpack the tuple on the fly:

```
if ((res, val) := myfunc(-2))[0]:
    print(val)
else:
    print('That was False')

     File "<ipython-input-10-03724761d41a>", line 20
    if ((res, val) := myfunc(-2))[0]:
        ^
SyntaxError: cannot use named assignment with tuple
```

Answer (score 0):

So it seems it’s not possible. 
I wanted to assign and test on the same statement like one can do in Go.

Closing this.